# How to use transaction when using trigger in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii, triggers, transactions

I have `accounts` and `money` tables in my MySQL database,so if any rows add to money,`accounts.balance` should be updated,first I did it by Active Record and Transaction

```
$transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    if ($createModel->save()) {
                $account = $createModel->accounts;
                $account->balance += $createModel->amount;
                if ($account->save())
                     $transaction->commit();

    }
} catch(Exception $e){
        $transaction->rollBack();
}
```

now I changed it to `$createModel->save()` and create trigger to update `accounts` table,

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_money BEFORE INSERT ON money
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
                UPDATE accounts SET balance=balance+NEW.amount WHERE id=NEW.accounts_id;
        END;
```

is trigger enough to be sure about updating accounts table with out using transaction?if your answer is no,How can I combine trigger,transaction and ActiveRecord?

Comment: Why are you doing *that* through a trigger? What's wrong with a transaction?

Comment: I think it's faster,and it help me to have thinner Controller.

Comment: *Thinking* that something is faster is not the same as *measuring* that it actually is faster. And even if it is slightly faster, you're still using a pancake to kill a wasp, your solution might work but it's not what triggers are for.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your approach is good enough. Although I'd suggest 2 changes to your current trigger implementation (first is important second you can ignore):

1. You probably want an `AFTER` rather then `BEFORE` trigger. Meaning you want to make an `UPDATE` to `accounts` being sure that `INSERT` into money is successfully completed. `BEFORE` triggers are usually used to either alter values of a row being inserted or changed or prevent an operation on that row (e.g. violating a constraint or issuing `SIGNAL`).
2. Since your trigger is a one statement trigger you can ditch `BEGIN ... END` block. That way you don't need to change `DELIMITER`.

That being said your trigger might look like

```sql
TRIGGER before_insert_money 
BEFORE INSERT ON money
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE accounts 
     SET balance = balance + NEW.amount 
   WHERE id = NEW.accounts_id;
```

The question that remains **do you allow to update and delete your money records**? If yes then you have to implement complementary `AFTER UPDATE` and `AFTER DELETE` triggers to properly maintain account balance.

---

Now if you're not expecting huge amounts of data you might also consider to create a view or by other means (separete method) calculate an account balance on the fly with a simply query. That way you don't need to maintain account value, deal with discrepancies that might occur, and it's always precise.

Comment: @Moein7tl Did it help in any way?